# Excel(CountIf): Counting appearances of text string in row/column/sheet

Tags: excel, countif

Having trouble counting certain amounts of times a text string appears inside a spreadsheet. My string I am looking for is `ThinkCentre M700`. My string I am using is `=COUNTIF(B3:B900,”ThinkCentre\ \M700”)`. I am getting a return of zero every time.

Expecting a count how many times a text appears in a column of text.

Comment: if you are looking for `ThinkCentre M700` then the countif should be: `=COUNTIF(B3:B900,"ThinkCentre M700")`

Comment: But why are you using double backward slashes `\ \` ?

Comment: I get an error if I dont use double backslashes.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting when the slashes are added?

Comment: Can you post some copiable data, along with a screencap showing the error you have met with

Comment: [no backslashes](https://ibb.co/Nmkq8bV)

Comment: [Data](https://ibb.co/8r6ngZ6)